# Insert a random value from a php array in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to insert a random value from a php array into a mysql table.

My php array is `$profile_outM = (3,6,7)`

The following command works nicely and sets `user_profile` to 7 for all users having `user_UFR` equal to 2:

`` UPDATE `users` SET `user_profile` = '$profile_outM[3]'  WHERE `user_UFR`= 2 ``

But how can I select a random value from  `$profile_outM` ?

Best,

HERE is the solution (might not be very elegant / efficient) but it works:

1. Starting with `$profile_outM` as a string
2. I convert to an array and get the number of element

`profile2array = explode(",", $profile_outM);`

`$length_profile2array =  count($profile2array);`

3. Then

`"SET @myValues = '$profile_outM'"`

`` "UPDATE `users` SET `user_profile` = SUBSTRING_INDEX(REVERSE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@Values, ',', FLOOR(1+RAND()*$length_profile2array))),',',1) WHERE `user_UFR`=2" ``

4. This way, all users get a different value.

W

Comment: I always use `$val = $array[mt_rand(0, count($array) - 1];`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_rand()` as @Victorbzh mentioned, or you can use:

```
$val = $array[mt_rand(0, count($array) - 1];
```

The above generates a random number using `mt_rand($min, $max)` (`$max` is inclusive). Array indexes start from 0, and `count()` gets the number of elements in the array.

**Security Note 1:** `array_rand()` and `mt_rand()` do not generate cryptographically secure values. If you want cryptographically secure values, use `random_int()`

**Security Note 2**: `` UPDATE `users` SET `user_profile` = '$profile_outM[3]'  WHERE `user_UFR`= 2 ``: It seems you are not using prepared statements. Make sure to use prepared statements when you are using input from the user.

Comment: Thanks . But ```UPDATE `users` SET `user_profile` = array_rand($profile_outM,1) WHERE `user_UFR`=2``` does not work. I get an error : **FUNCTION up_idex.array_rand does not exist** (up_idex is my table).

Comment: @2WFR Oh god! Use ```UPDATE `users` SET `user_profile` = ". array_rand($profile_outM,1)."  WHERE `user_UFR`=2```

Comment: Thanks. No more error. But it still does not work as it picks up the same value for all users.

Comment: I guess I have to use some SQL functions like ```UPDATE `users` SET `user_profile` = FLOOR( 1 + RAND( ) *60 ) WHERE  `user_UFR`=2```. This sets a random number for all users (albeit this is not what I need as I need to pick up a value from an array).

Comment: @2WFR you could use my solution using `mt_rand` and try

Comment: Sorry but it does not work